# Ruby: Find an SQL record and update a boolean field

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I'm using Sinatra and the [mysql2](https://github.com/brianmario/mysql2) gem.

I'm trying to do a simple update of a field called "process_complete", which is a boolean.

My code is:

```
    user = User.first!(email: user_email)
    user.update(:process_complete => true)
```

I get the error:

```
19:30:05 web.1  |    INFO -  (0.000603s) SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE (`email` = 'user@email.com') LIMIT 1
19:30:05 web.1  | 2015-10-18 19:30:05 - Sequel::MassAssignmentRestriction - method process_complete= doesn't exist:
```

Am I doing something wrong here? When I look up `SELECT * FROM`users`WHERE (`email`= 'user@email.com') LIMIT 1` in mysql I see my user, and "process_complete" is set as `0`.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: http://sequel.jeremyevans.net/rdoc/files/doc/mass_assignment_rdoc.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
user = User.where(email: user_email).first
user.process_complete = true
user.save
```